# PHP: mysqli_connect vs mysqli : Checking an open connection using mysqli_ping

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I have a few functions which take an optional `$connection` parameter (defaults to null).  If it is not set or is empty I want to re-open or spawn a new database connection, so I perform this check:

`if(empty($connection) || mysqli_connect_errno() || !mysqli_ping($connection)) $connection = connect();`

My `connect()` function is below, but basically it returns a `mysqli_connect` resource:

```
function connect() {
  $hostname = getDBHostname();
  $dbusername = getDBUsername();
  $dbpassword = getDBPassword();
  $dbname = getDBDatabase();
  $connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
  if($connection == false) {
    die('Database Connection Initialization Failed');
  }
  else if($connection->connect_error) {
    die('Fatal DB Connect Error ('.$connection->connect_errno.') '.$connection->connect_error);
  }
  $test = mysqli_select_db($connection, $dbname);
  return $connection;
}
```

These are resulting in a bunch of these warnings:

`Warning: mysqli_ping(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/html/project/functions.php on line 123`

I realized that passing `mysqli_ping` a `mysqli_connect` `$link` is a mistake over a `mysqli` object, but then **how can I possibly check to see if my `mysqli_connect` object is set and open?** and if it's not, open it?

Comment: Try to make $connection as global variable.

Comment: Let me ask you something: At any point in your script, do you close the connection yourself by using mysq_close() or $connection->close() before all actions are performed?

Comment: Global might be a valid work around, but it doesn't strictly answer this question.  Yes, I do call mysqli_close and it's possible it happens, then the connection is attempted again. That's why I want to reopen if it is closed (or spawn a new connection entirely) which is what mysqli_ping should do, but for a different object type (mysqli_ping needs a mysqli object, but I'm working with mysqli_connect objects).

Answer (score 0):

All right, so here's my answer:

The mysqli_ping documentation says:

> Checks whether the connection to the server is working. If it has gone down ... This function can be used by clients that ***remain idle for a long while, to check whether the server has closed the connection and reconnect if necessary***.

The problem is you're assuming `mysqli_ping` will work when the connection is closed manually, but the function does not work like that.

If you close your connection manually, the object still exists but points to a closed connection that cannot be pinged or reopened by this function / method. Just as if you'd use `$connection->ping()` after closing it.

When you say that:

> I realized that passing mysqli_ping a mysqli_connect $link is a mistake over a mysqli object ...

It's not correct. A connection object (either returned by `mysqli_connect` or created with the mysqli constructor) is the only type or argument the function accepts.

You can try:

- Not closing the connection until the end of the script

Or

- Unsetting the connection variable after each time you close it with `unset($connection)`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am already doing the `unset($connection)` after any given `mysqli_close($connection)` calls.

Comment: Ok, follow up question: Do you always pass the $connection parameter or do you omit it in some functions? Follow up to the follow up: Does it always show the warning or just when passed or omitted?

Comment: Also, I hope you're not unsetting the $connection object outside of its scope, like inside one of the functions you are using. Because doing so will only unset the local $connection and not the global one, unless it was passed by reference with the `&` operator.

Comment: I'm still tracing it, but it looks like it's only displaying warnings when passed, but even then maybe not always -- still looking.  I AM NOT passing by reference, but my design was that it would only close if it was NOT passed to begin with.  The idea being: You sent me a connection? okay, I'll use it and leave it alone.  You didn't send me one?  I'll get my own and destroy it when I'm done.

Comment: I hope you can crack this one down. I would still recommend not using `mysqli_connect_errno()` check because you seem to have the connection very well controlled in your `connect()` function, and the `mysqli_ping()` because I don't think it's necessary. I think you should be good enough with `empty($connection)`. But that's just my opinion.